# Overriding Mocked objects declared in different files for Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I've got a test-setup file which handles some generic before's that apply to multiple test files.
I'm mocking an object which I need in several of those tests.

I'd like to be able to override it on a test by test basis.

How can I access it since it's located in a different file? I assume I can use `module.exports = myMockedObject;` and then `const myMockedObject = require('./test-setup.js');`

Is there a way that Mocha allows you to share a scope between your test files?

Comment: well I mean that if I define a variable in `/tests/test-setup.js` I can automagically access that same variable from `/tests/mytest.js` . something like a mocha tests global scope or shared scope.

Comment: How exactly is it supposed to be used? Please, show some code.